# TypeError for BayesianOptimization bayes_opt

Tags: xgboost, bayesian, hyperparameters

I am following a tutorial on hyperparameter tuning online and I am trying to use `bayes_opt` but I get this error:

```py
---> best_params = bo.res['max']['max_params']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Here is my sample code:

```py
from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization

bo= BayesianOptimization(xgb_evaluate, {'max_depth': (3, 7), 
                                             'gamma': (0, 1),
                                             'colsample_bytree': (0.3, 0.9)})
bo.maximize(init_points=3, n_iter=5, acq='ei')

best_params = bo.res['max']['max_params']
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that I was using a newer version of `bayes_opt` and the API changed. To get the best parameters, all I had to do was just to search for the max target value, then get the params:

```py
params = max(xgb_bo.res, key=lambda x:x['target'])
best_params = params['params']
best_target = params['target']
best_params['max_depth'] = int(best_params['max_depth'])
print(best_target, best_params)
```